# rescue data of scrachted bluray/dvd with broken toc/index

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, blu-ray, ddrescue, udf

My goal is to rescue data from a scratched/broken Blu-ray (probably similar to DVD)
I used Linux with ddrescue and recovered 98% of the blocks during its first run:

```
ddrescue -n -b2048 /dev/sr1 cdimage.iso mapfile
```

Unfortunately mounting the iso only gave access to about 50% of the data.

```
mount -o loop,ro img.iso /mnt
```

The folders containing the rest of the data are shown with ”?” for privileges and size and date which normally indicates file system problems.
It seems the scratch affected the toc/index of the  file system (probably udf). **Is there a way to repair the toc / index to access the rest of the recovered blocks?**

```
259  2 drwxrwxrwx 9 nobody nogroup 444 Dez 21  2015 .
5    4 drwxrwxrwx 9 nobody nogroup 444 May 3   7:50 ..
261  2 drwxrwxrwx 9 nobody nogroup 444 Dez 21  2015 workin_directory
?    ? ?????????  ? ?      ?       ?   ?       ?    brocken dir
```

Further Recovery with ddrescue might rescue further block using other options -r3, -R and so on, but worst case it might only gather further data blocks, which are again not accessible because of broken toc / index / file system.

Comment: Once finished with ddrescue, running photorec on the image may rescue data depending on what was stored. (Photorec looks at the raw data - but looses thongs like filenames. Not important for pucs, but frustrating for other docs.)

Comment: Sounds good, for now I tried ddrescue with -s400M option to focus on the first 400MB of the BluRay which seem to contain the folder structure, which slowly recovers ...